# How to get health of an entity holding enchanted item

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I am currently trying to make a Minecraft mod in Fabric, and part of it is an enchantment that changes attack damage based on the health of the entity holding it. Currently, I believe I have a method that gets the health of an entity,

```
public static float getUserHealth(LivingEntity user) {
        return user.getHealth();
    }
```

However, I cannot find a way to get the entity so I can run this.

So, does anyone know how to get the entity holding the enchanted item so I can use it in this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, where I didn't use the getAttackDamage method, and instead just got and set the health of the target within the onTargetDamaged method, as that by default has the user as a parameter